# postfix/qmgr error - connect to private/dovecot No such file or directory

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot

I have a Ubuntu 18.0.4 bionic with postfix and dovecot and dovecot-mysql installed.  Receiving the errors shown on lines 1 and 2:

```
Jul  4 15:58:05 mailer postfix/qmgr[11870]: warning: connect to transport private/dovecot: No such file or directory
Jul  4 15:58:05 mailer postfix/error[1463]: EDCC317B342: to=<sfullman@paybycompass.com>, relay=none, delay=0.09, delays=0.07/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
Jul  4 15:58:05 mailer postfix/smtpd[1456]: disconnect from mail-io1-f44.google.com[209.85.166.44] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
```

I do not understand the message `warning: connect to transport private/dovecot: No such file or directory`; is `private/dovecot` the file/folder it's referring to or is it a process?  I've done a grep through the entire `/etc/postfix` file to figure out what `private/dovecot` is, and don't see the pattern.

**UPDATE:** by trial and error I have found that `private/{process_name}` comes from the postfix `main.cf` setting `virtual_transport = {process_name}` - it can be dovecot or mailman or whatever - but why am I still getting the no such file or directory message..

Answer (score 2):

Answer: there are two parts to this.

1) `private/{process_name}` actually references `/var/spool/postfix/private/{process_name}` which you can check to see if it's there.  I discovered this from https://www.howtoforge.com/postfix-dovecot-warning-sasl-connect-to-private-auth-failed-no-such-file-or-directory and extrapolated from that path..

```
[...] (sample code for a process mapping)
client {
   path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
   mode = 0660
   user = postfix
   group = postfix
}
[...]
```

2) after that I realized it was a user error (myself), and with `service postfix restart` the process showed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem about transport private/dovecot and I solved it. I didn't change /etc/dovecot.conf nor /etc/postfix/main.cf. I did the following actions:

First, execute vi /etc/postfix/master.cf, then:

```
1) Uncomment:
  1.1) submission inet n line with -o lines
  2.2) smtps inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd with -o lines

2) Add at the end of the file
   dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}

3) Finally, restart postfix service.
```